# Errors with Get-ChildItem trying to scan network for all .mdb files

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, get-childitem

I am very new to using powershell and trying to execute a script that scans the entire network for all .mdb and .accdb files, for example, and generates a spreadsheet containing the data on them that I process elsewhere.

I put the sensistive data that I didnt want to provide in ()s

Here is my code:

```
#single threaded
import-module activedirectory

$arr = @()

$computers = Get-ADComputer -filter 'name -like "(employee computers)*"'  | Select -Exp Name

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
Write-Host "Scanning" $computer "..."
gci \\$computer\c$\* -Include *.mdb, *.accdb -Recurse | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $False} | % {
$obj = New-Object PSObject
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Directory $_.DirectoryName
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Name $_.Name
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty FullName $_.FullName
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Size $_.Length
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty CreationTime $_.CreationTime
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty LastWriteTime $_.LastWriteTime

$arr += $obj
Write-Host "Scanning..." 
}}

$arr | Export-CSV -notypeinformation '(path)\EmployeeDBs.csv'
```

This has been working pretty well so far, but for certain machines and/or directories on some machines I am receiving the following error messages:

```
Get-ChildItem : The specified network name is no longer available

[Get-ChildItem], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

and

```
Get-ChildItem : An object at the specified path \\(employee computer)\c$ does not exist.

[Get-ChildItem], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemDoesNotExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

I have been googling around but havent had much luck in understanding these error messages. Would somebody be able to explain what the issues are?

I am thinking (hoping) that they are permissions problems because I am testing the scripts on my personal machine before I run them from the admin machine

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: below is my edited code for asynchronous execution:

```
import-module activedirectory

$computers = Get-ADComputer -filter 'name -like "wa-150*"'  | Select -Exp Name


Get-job | Remove-Job -Force
Remove-Item -path (path)\EmployeeDBs.txt

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $scriptBlock = {gci \\$($args[0])\c$\Users\z*\Desktop\* -Include *.mdb, *.accdb -Recurse | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $False} | % {
        $obj = New-Object PSObject
        $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Directory $_.DirectoryName
        $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Name $_.Name
        $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Size $_.Length
        $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty CreationTime $_.CreationTime
        $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty LastWriteTime $_.LastWriteTime
        Write-Output -InputObject $obj
        }
    }

    while ((Get-Job -State Running).Count -ge 20) {
        Write-Host "Full - Waiting ... "
      Start-Sleep -Seconds 5;
    }

    Start-Job -name $computer -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList $computer
    #Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList $computer

}
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job | Out-File -Append -FilePath '(path)\EmployeeDBs.txt'
Write-Host "Done"
```

Comment: the message usually means that either [a] the target system was offline, [b] it is online, but failed to respond in time, or [c] the name has something wrong with it - perhaps a trailing space? ///// the usual fix is to add a `Test-Path` or `Test-Connection` before you try to access it. [*grin*]

Comment: argh! i just reread your error msgs ... do you REALLY have `(employee computers)` in your computer names? does a name with `()`s in it work?

Comment: For the second error, I bet it happens when the full URI (i.e. "\\computer\C$\dir\dir\file.ext") is longer than 255 chars.

Comment: You might find it better to run remote PowerShell commands on the computers in the domain. You can have them run asynchronously and consolidate the results once they are all finished.

Comment: Question - do you know for a fact that none of the computers have multiple volumes? You are only scanning the C: drive but what if they have others?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey the (employee computers) is just a place holder for "WA-150*" which does capture all of the machines. (they all start with WA-150).

Comment: @Max It gave me the "Does not exist" error when it tried to scan my friends computer who works next to me, then I had him run the same script on his computer and it worked for him. Thats why I am thinking its a permissions issue, I was just confused why it says "does not exist" or "no longer available"

Comment: @TechnoTone I have another script that scans all of the shared drives individually. The same happens for them as well. I would say the outputted spreadhseet contains about 80% of the data, losing about 20% due to these errors being generated for certain computers/paths. I dont really know what you mean by your first comment but i will start googling around for running commands in the domain/asynchronous execution. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @TechnoTone "You can have them run asynchronously and consolidate the results once they are all finished"  Can you elaborate on this? I have been trying to mess around with Start-Job and ScriptBlocks but have had no luck

Comment: @wp26 - thank you for the added info. i am  out of ideas and will go back to lurking. good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: Have you had a look at Invoke-Command?

Comment: @TechnoTone Thanks for your response. I got it to work with Start-Job and it seems to work well (execution time went from 8 to 1.5 hours!) so thanks for you help. I edited the post to include the code change. When I tried Invoke-Command it didnt seem to execute the next scriptblock until the previous had finished running. While I am grateful for your insight with making it more efficient, do you have a response to my initial question regarding  seemingly random paths getting skipped with those errors saying the path doesnt exist when it does?